# pyodbc - add column to MS Access with default value

Tags: python-3.x, ms-access, pyodbc, alter-table

I'm trying to add a column to an MS Access database table using pyodbc and Python 3.5.

Using the expression

```
self.cursor.execute("ALTER TABLE data ADD COLUMN testColumn TEXT(10)")
```

works fine, but when I try to add a default value (DEFAULT "no"), it throws a Syntax error. I've tried multiple combinations, but no luck.

Any help is much appreciated!

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sadly, the Access ODBC driver simply does not support the `DEFAULT` clause for a column in `CREATE/ALTER TABLE` statements. The ODBC driver and OLEDB provider for Access have diverged somewhat in their DDL support, so unfortunately we can get inconsistent results for the same DDL statement as illustrated by the following VBScript code using ADO:

OLEDB works fine ...

```vbs
Option Explicit
Dim conn
Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Dim connStr
connStr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Public\mdbTest.mdb"
conn.Open connStr

On Error Resume Next
conn.Execute "DROP TABLE Cheeses"
On Error GoTo 0
conn.Execute "CREATE TABLE Cheeses (Id LONG PRIMARY KEY, CheeseName TEXT(50) DEFAULT 'Cheddar')"

conn.Execute "INSERT INTO Cheeses (Id) VALUES (1)"

Dim rst
Set rst = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
rst.Open "SELECT CheeseName FROM Cheeses WHERE Id = 1", conn
If rst("CheeseName").Value = "Cheddar" Then
    WScript.Echo "Success"
End If

conn.Close
```

... but if we change the connection string to use ODBC ...

```vbs
connStr = "Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};Dbq=C:\Users\Public\mdbTest.mdb"
```

... then our attempt to execute the `CREATE TABLE` statement fails with

> Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers: [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Syntax error in CREATE TABLE statement.

TL;DR - You can't use the `DEFAULT` clause in a `CREATE/ALTER TABLE` statement under pyodbc.

Comment: Thanks for your reply and explanation Gord. I ended up creating the (empty) column and then filled it with the default values by running an Update query. Not pretty or efficient, but good enough for my purposes for now.

Comment: Great answer. Official documentation is lacking (or permanently gone/obsolete!), but https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office2000/aa140015(v=office.10) has the following line which I think is relevant: `The DEFAULT statement can be executed only through the Jet OLE DB provider and ADO. It will return an error message if used through the Access SQL View user interface.` My own experiments in C# and .NET show that the ODBC driver has the same issue with `DEFAULT`, but that OleDB works.